# slots in grid-template-column

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have the below HTML markup:

```
<sl-responsive-media >
    <slot name="image"> 
    </slot>
</sl-responsive-media>
    <slot name="header" part="header"></slot>
<sl-divider>
    <slot name="divider"> 
    </slot>
</sl-divider>
<slot name="text" part="text"></slot>
<slot name="link" part="link"></slot>
```

I am trying to place the HTML in the below grid fashion:

[image]

CSS tried:

```
:host {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 
      'image . header . 'auto
      '. . divider .'auto
      '. . text .'auto
      '. . link .'auto
       /4fr 4fr
      }
```

This css is not working. I' not getting 2 columns created correctly. Any help pls?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I'm able to figure out the answer myself:

```
:host {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-areas:
      "image header"
      "image divider"
      "image text"
      "image link";
      grid-gap: 1em;
     }

slot[name='image']::slotted(*){
      grid-area: image;
    }
slot[name='header']::slotted(*) {
      grid-area: header;
    }

    slot[name='divider']::slotted(*) {
      grid-area: divider;
    }

 slot[name='text']::slotted(*) {
      grid-area: text;
    }

    slot[name='link']::slotted(*) {
      grid-area: link;
    }
```

This perfectly assigns the slots to corresponding grid area.